# Node.js compile on save

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, vscode-tasks

I have an Angular app compiling on save thanks to an autogenerated tsconfig file, but I can't figure out how to do the same for a Node.js server. Do I need to modify launch.json to reference another tsconfig.json somehow?

Here is my launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "ng serve",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "npm: start",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
          },
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch JS",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/app/nodeapi/nodeapi.js"
        }
    ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2018",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

my project structure:

```
|src
|-app
|--app.component.ts and other .TS files
|--nodeapi
|---nodeapi.js <---contains my server code
|tsconfig.json (shown above)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use nodemon for this and saving your application will automatically compile

Comment: Once I've installed nodemon what files would I need to modify? The launch config?

Comment: @Rilcon42, you don't have to modify any file for this. you have to run the command ``nodemon nodeapi.js`` for this in command prompt

Answer (score 0):

You can install nodemon using Angular CLI . Nodemon is a task watcher which will automatically compile you server side/API's on save.

Comment: Once I've installed nodemon what files would I need to modify? The launch config?